# Use loop to find the node value with a similar node name

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying implement a test with Selenium and C# which reads an XML config file and perform an automated test. My XML is shown below:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="Url" value=" http://book.jetstar.com/"/>

  <!--Id's or Xpath-->  <!--LOCATOR-->
  <add key="Origin" value="somevalue"/>
  <add key="Destination" value="somevalue"/>
  <add key="Adult" value ="somevalue" />
  <add key="SearchFlights" value ="somevalue"/>

  <!--Controls-->
  <add key="OriginCtrl" value=" Input"/>
  <add key="DestinationCtrl" value=" Input"/>
  <add key="AdultCtrl" value=" Select"/>
  <add key="SearchFlightsCtrl " value=" Button"/>

</appSettings>
```

The process intended to be:

1. Read through XML file and get values of "Key" and "value", determine the node is "Locator" or "Controller" by checking whether the "Key" has the text "Ctrl".
2. While a Locator is determined , loop through the XML and find the relative "Controller"
   E.g:  A locator "Origin" has a controller called "OriginCtrl".

   3.Get "value" of this controller and parse it through other methods.

Now I am confused at the process for finding the relative controller of object. I have used the following code to get value of nodes, however I could not find a way to 'Continue' the loop while a Locator is found and search its Controller.

```
 xmlDoc.Load(filename);
            XmlNodeList elemList = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("add");

            for (int i = 0; i < elemList.Count; i++)
            {
                  string keyname = elemList[i].Attributes["key"].Value;
                  string keyvalue = elemList[i].Attributes["value"].Value;
            }
```

Any hints or suggestions on how to implement this process will be highly appreciated.

Comment: why are you not using xml serialization class for this?

Comment: I concur with Arijit. You should be storing this information in a structured format. Using `appSettings` for this is problematic, as you have already found.

Comment: @JLRishe posted an answer as per the users choice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using `XmlDocument`, combination of [`SelectNodes()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcebdtae%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [`SelectSingleNode()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb63z0tw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and a proper XPath argument is very handy to select any specific part of the XML document, for example :

```
xmlDoc.Load(filename);
//select all <add> nodes having key attribute
XmlNodeList elemList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//add[@key]");
foreach(XmlNode add in elemList)
{
    string keyname = add.Attributes["key"].Value;
    string keyvalue = add.Attributes["value"].Value;

    //if current node is not a controller, get corresponding controller
    if (!keyname.EndsWith("Ctrl"))
    {
        string xpath = String.Format("../add[contains(@key, '{0}Ctrl')]", keyname);
        var controller = add.SelectSingleNode(xpath);
        var value = "";
        if(controller != null)
        {
            value = controller.Attributes["value"].Value;
            Console.WriteLine(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best I can think of is, generate equivalent class for this, using xsd.exe

After that, is will just two Dictionaries with key value pair.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code its tested and working

**Explanation :**

It first Checks for the Locator and then for the locator value it search for the specified controller and assign its value to 'value2'

```
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.LoadXml(filename);
        XmlNodeList elemList = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("add");
        for (int i = 0; i < elemList.Count; i++)
        {
            string keyname = elemList[i].Attributes["key"].Value;
            string keyvalue = elemList[i].Attributes["value"].Value;
            if (!keyname.EndsWith("Ctrl"))
            {
                for(int j = 0 ; j < elemList.Count; j++)
                {
                    bool xmlnode = elemList[j].Attributes["key"]
                                   .Value.Equals(keyname + "Ctrl");
                    if (xmlnode)
                    {
                        string value2 = elemList[j].Attributes["value"].Value;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do. With this approach you will only traverse the half file. Thus it will be much faster than the other way around.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        XDocument xDocument =
            XDocument.Load(@"C:\Visual Studio\Projects\ConsoleApplication3\ConsoleApplication3\config.xml");

        if (xDocument != null)
        {
            var locators = from x in xDocument.Descendants("add")
                where !x.Attribute("key").Value.EndsWith("Ctrl")
                select x;

            if (locators.Any())
            {
                foreach (var locator in locators)
                {
                    var controller = from c in xDocument.Descendants("add")
                        where
                            c.Attribute("key")
                                .Value.Equals(locator.Attribute("key").Value + "ctrl",
                                    StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) 
                        select c;

                    if (controller.Any())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(controller.First().Attribute("value"));
                    }

                }


            }
        }
    }
}
```